# Is it possible to do automatic rollback in bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

In Bamboo, Is it possible to do an automatic rollback to the previous release, based on the result of the deployment project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can potentially have some post-deploy tests or otherwise determine if deployment has failed. If it has failed, kick-start/trigger the deployment project with older release! Refer the comments here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14079